# Reproduce a prior density plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, distribution, probability-density, mle

I am still getting used to converting formulas to code in R. I am trying to work through the empirical Bayes chapter (chapter 6) in [Computer Age Statistical Inference](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/PDF/casi.pdf). I would like to produce plot 6.4, but in order to do so I need to find the marginal distribution of a function of the data.

To obtain the the data and plot it I did the following.

```
nodes <- read.table("https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/DATA/nodes.txt",
           header = T)

nodes %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=x/n))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 30)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "nodes",
       n = "p=x/n")
```

[image]

He then tries the following model

[image]

With the following calculations

[image]

To get the plot I am trying to reproduce.

[image]

I am used to using standard R functions for inference such as `lm()` and
`glm()`, but now that I need to maximize a mle to find a marginal distribution I am lost.

Comment: Have a look at `geom_freqpoly`

Comment: @S Rivero i am struggling more with the mle part. I think I will use 'stat_function' once I figure out the density.

Comment: I think you need to post on CrossValidated.com. You are not presenting a specific method that determines a coded solution. You need theoretical support. The illustration does not appear to be explained by the copied text and I do not see the plot of `g()hat+sd` versus `theta` as illustrating what a histogram represents, but I could be wrong. I'm guessing the two little blue arrows are showing minima in the likelihoods and that there is a lesson to be learned that is explained elsewhere in the text..

Comment: @42- you may be right about posting this question on CrossValidated. Also, I fixed the plot to include the description.

Comment: @42- Also, including the `+sd` is not important to me. I am just trying to get the same marginal distribution in `R`.

Comment: Ah. I now see that red bars are the "sd"'s and the `g(theta)` is the black line. So I would reproduce that with cuts of `x/n` at `breaks=seq(0,1,length=100)`. It still doesn't look like your plot matches Efron/Hastie's plot since their's shows fitted proportions rather than counts.

Comment: Thinking about trying to do this with "traditional methods" I would suggest using a polynomial spline fit to the density of observations of `x/n`.

Comment: @42- That is exactly what I am trying to do. He fit a 4th order polynomial.