# Example of fitting marginal distributions to histogram in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, distribution, bayesian

Could someone show me how to fit a polynomial marginal distribution to my data? I have done a binomial and beta binomial, but I would like to see how to fit a polynomial. I would also be interested in trying a gamma if that is something you know how to do.

This is what I have done so far.

```
nodes <- read.table("https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/CASI_files/DATA/nodes.txt",
           header = T)

nodes %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=x/n))+
  geom_histogram(bins = 30)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "nodes",
       n = "p=x/n")

# log-likelihood function
ll <- function(alpha, beta) {
x <- nodes$x
total <- nodes$n
-sum(VGAM::dbetabinom.ab(x, total, alpha, beta, log = TRUE))
}

# maximum likelihood estimation
m <- mle(ll, start = list(alpha = 1, beta = 10), method = "L-BFGS-B",
lower = c(0.0001, .1))
ab <- coef(m)
alpha0 <- ab[1]
beta0 <- ab[2]

nodes %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x/n, y = ..density..), bins= 30) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dbeta(x, alpha0, beta0), color = "red",
                size = 1) +
  xlab("p=x/n")
```

[image]

Here is another fit

```
ll <- function(a){
  x <- nodes$x
  total <- nodes$n
  -sum(stats::dbinom(x, total, a, log = TRUE))
}

#stats::dbinom()
m <- mle(ll, start = list(a=.5), method = "L-BFGS-B",
lower = c(0.0001, .1))

a = coef(m)

nodes %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x/n, y = ..density..), bins=40) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dbeta(x, a, 1), color = "red",
                size = 1) +
  xlab("proportion x/n")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For fitting a gamma distribution:

```
data(iris)
library(MASS) ##for the fitdistr function

fit.params <- fitdistr(iris$Sepal.Length, "gamma", lower = c(0, 0))

ggplot(data = iris) + 
 geom_histogram(data = as.data.frame(x), aes(x=iris$Sepal.Length, y=..density..)) +
 geom_line(aes(x=iris$Sepal.Length, 
 y=dgamma(iris$Sepal.Length,fit.params$estimate["shape"], 
 fit.params$estimate["rate"])), color="red", size = 1) + 
 theme_classic()
```

You might also like to take a look at the distribution of the quantiles using the qqp function in the car package. Here are a few examples:

```
library(car)
qqp(iris$Sepal.Length, "norm") ##normal distribution

qqp(iris$Sepal.Length, "lnorm") ##log-normal distribution

gamma <- fitdistr(iris$Sepal.Length, "gamma")
qqp(iris$Sepal.Length, "gamma", shape = gamma$estimate[[1]], 
 rate = gamma$estimate[[2]]) ##gamma distribution

nbinom <- fitdistr(iris$Sepal.Length, "Negative Binomial")
qqp(iris$Sepal.Length, "nbinom", size = nbinom$estimate[[1]], 
 mu = nbinom$estimate[[2]]) ##negative binomial distribution
```

You can use the fitdistr function for ggplots or qqPlots. It supports lots of different distributions. Take a look at ?fitdistr

Comment: how would I fit a custom polynomial?  Does fitdistr allow for that?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what your goal is here? I've just never heard of fitting a custom polynomial to a histogram. If you want to fit a custom polynomial regression, you can use the lm() function.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to replicate a plot from a previous post, but I am still unsure how to do it, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290265/reproduce-a-prior-density-plot-in-r

Comment: Thanks for linking to the further details. I've spent some time toying around with this, and I'm afraid I'm not sure what else to try. Perhaps someone else will chime in. Best of luck.